# How to query Entity Framework objects where select is a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to do something simple, but I can't figure it out.  Using EF6, I have 2 tables which are associated by an intermediate associative table, giving a many-to-many relationship:

[image: 2 associated tables Users and Families]

I want to query all users who belong to a list of families.  So I get an array of families:

```
var db = new MyProjectEntities(); 
User user = GetUserById((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUserId"]);
var families = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == user.UserId).First().Families.ToArray();
```

Then I want to query all users belonging to these families:

```
var users = db.Users.Where(u => families.Contains(u.Families));
```

But I get this error:

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'Database.Family[]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable>'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Any method:

```
var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Families.Any(fam => families.Contains(fam))).AsEnumerable();
```

I think this is what you're searching for.

Comment: I just had to insert .AsEnumerable() to avoid the 'Unable to create a constant value of type ...' error.

Comment: Yea it must be enumerated, sorry for ambiguity